# Email validation not working using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate for form validation.
There is only one element in the form as of now.Others will be added later.The `form_email` field is required.

here is my script with html

```
    <form novalidate="novalidate" name="Emergency Contact Form" action="#" id="form_3" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group act">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">What is your email address? <span class="required">* </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="18" name="form_email" class="form-control element" type="email">
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <button type="button" id="btn18" class="btn green">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_3").validate({
            rules: {
              form_email: { required: true,email: true} 
            },
            messages: {
              form_email: { required:"We require your email address to proceed" }
            }
         });
         $("#btn18").on("click",function(){
             if($("#form_3").valid()){
                getNextQuestion(elementVal);
             }
         });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is that when I keep the email field empty and click the button it does not give the validation msg. But when I enter an invalid email address(asdf@ghjk.) and click the button it gives the validation msg('Please enter a valid email address.').
Why is it not giving validation msg when field is empty.
These html elements are injected through ajax.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The code you've presented properly gives the message when the field is left empty: http://jsfiddle.net/ebord060 ~ Please provide something that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Sparky yes I know this works on jsfidle. But not in my project. The whole div(class="form-body")  along with jquery in the form gets loaded through ajax. and then it doesnt work as expected. Any fix for this.

Comment: Got the answer form.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation"); does the trick

Comment: If it does not work in the project, but the code you show us is working, then the question does not help us answer anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add into the rules -

```
required: true,
minlength: 2,
```

and in messages add -

```
required: "Required input",
minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is looking ok. Made small test case and everything works as expected.

Problem can occure when you click on button before DOM loaded event was fired. There will be no events attached to button and validation won't trigger in this case. You should try debugging it. There probably something on page that blocking page to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code I have made some change hope this will help you

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" name="Emergency Contact Form" action="#" id="form_3" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group act">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">What is your email address? <span class="required">* </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="18" name="form_email" class="form-control element" type="email">
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <button type="button" id="btn18" class="btn green">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#form_3").submit(function (event) {
            var email = $('#18').val();
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            if (email != '' && email != null && emailReg.test( email )) {
                alert('is valid');
            } else {
                alert('not valid');
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#btn18").on("click", function () {
            $('#form_3').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This can help 

<html>
<head>

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load jQuery and the validate plugin -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Form Validation code -->
  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Register here</h1>

  <!--  The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit  -->
  <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div class="label">Password</div><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

  </form>

</body>
</html>

Cheers,

Murali P
```

Comment: this works but this is on form submit. I want to make it on button click.